# how to get a tooltip to work inside an existing JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

here is my function:

```
function passwordValidation(){

    var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";


    if (uname.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else if (uname.length < 6){
            $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#myToolTip').tooltip();
            });
    }else if (pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else if (pword1.value == cPassword.value){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else if  (pword1.value != cPassword.value){
        match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
}
```

this function works fine without the first else if. but once i include it, nothing will work. interestingly, if i put the else if isolated on it's own it also works. well actually, this works:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
                $('#myToolTip').tooltip();
```

how can i combine the 2 so that when the user enters something less than 6 characters, the tooltip will flash up telling them what they need to change

Comment: This code is getting progressively worse as your questions about it continue.

Comment: The first if statement that validates as true will be fired. So you have to figure out a good way of organizing your validations. As a sidenote; the document.ready wrapper should not be within the if statement.

Comment: @Jamiec please explain?

Comment: @Baszz that was going to be the central point of my next question. is there a good way to be able to run lots of different scripts or if statements so that you can have multiple things running? because currently my if statement is just expanding and like you said, as soon as one hits true the others will not even be trialed. is there a neat tidy way?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a `$(document).ready()` here, just use

```
else if (uname.length < 6){
    $('#myToolTip').tooltip();
}
```

(As an aside, if you *did* want a document ready, it cant be within an if statement like this, and there should be no quotes round the `document` bit)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#pword1').tooltip();
    $('#pword1').tooltip( "disable" );
    $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();
});

function passwordValidation(){

    var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
    var cPassword = document.getElementById("cPassword");

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";

    var match ="";
    if (uname.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else if (uname.length < 6){
        $('#pword1').tooltip( "enable" );
        $('#pword1').tooltip("open");
    }else if (pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else if (pword1.value == cPassword.value){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else if  (pword1.value != cPassword.value){
        match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
}
```

The tooltip is disabled when the page loads. It is enabled and shown when the user clicks validation button and your condition is met.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wrj6da3/

Comment: copied and pasted this over my function just to see what it would do and nothing worked. do you know why? html need editing?

Comment: Updated my answer with a fiddle.